# IBM Worklight 6.2 - CLI invoke returns status code 505

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-cli

I am using IBM Worklight 6.2 CLI tools to create and invoke a procedure on my adapter. When I pass in a parameter that contains a **space** character, I get back an error:

```
wl invoke
[?] Which procedure do you want to invoke? submitNotification
[?] Enter the comma-separated parameters: "user", "hello hello"
Invoking PushAdapter:submitNotification...
Arguments:
[
  "user",
  "hello hello"
]
Invocation result:
Status Code: 505 HTTP Version Not Supported
```

Nothing gets logged on the server and no useful messages in the trace file. This does not happen if I pass a parameter that doesn't have a space character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug. Next fixpack you contain the fix. Or if you are an IBM customer you can open PMR to get an ifix when is available.

To workaround encode the spaces with '%20'

```
$ wl invoke
[?] Which procedure do you want to invoke? submitNotification
[?] Enter the comma-separated parameters: "user", "hello%20hello"
Invoking PushAdapter:submitNotification...
Arguments:
[
  "user",
  "hello%20hello"
]
Invocation result:
{
```

...